# Android auto change riyal symbol in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to render riyal symbol in my react native project (saudi arabia currency).
What i am dong is: 
`<Text>﷼</Text>`
And the symbol that i expect it will render on my app is:
[image: Riyal symbol]

On IOS it renders exactly like what i expected but on Android it renders other currency which is like the following image:
[image]